# How to assign the value of $filenameTosTor for my 'photo' which is a database column?

Tags: laravel

What to here ?
how to assign the value of `$filenameTosTor` for my 'photo' which is a database column?

```
public function update(Request $request, User $user)
{        
    $filenameWithExt = $request->file('profile_pic')->getClientOriginalName();

    $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    Get the Extention
    $extention = $request->file('profile_pic')->getClientOriginalExtension();

    $filenameToStore  = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extention;

    $path  = $request->file('profile_pic')->storeAs('public/profile_image', $filenameToStore);


    $userupdate = User::where('id', $user->id)->update
    ([
        'name' => $request->input('name'),
        $user->profile_pic =$filenameToStore;
        'photo'=> $request->($filenameToStore);
        'last_name' => $request->input('last_name'),
        'phone_number' => $request->input('phone_number'),
        'address' => $request->input('address'),
        'facebook_link' => $request->input('facebook_link'),
        'twittr_link' => $request->input('twittr_link'),
        'youtube_link' => $request->input('youtube_link'),
        'Biography' => $request->input('Biography'),
    ]);
    $userupdate->save();
    return redirect('user.index');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this variable like this:

```
'photo' => $filenameToStore,
```

Comment: thanks but i need to asssign the value of $filenameToStore for my 'photo' , and as i put it i make error.

Comment: semi colon is not allowed inside the the array

Comment: @Najibjamshidi why don't you remove it?